# Full text catalog missing a keyword

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search, catalogs

We have a full text catalog on one of our databases but one keyword does not work.

e.g:

```
select * from table where name = 'jon' -- result set returns as expected  
select * from table where Contains(a.Name, '"jon"') -- no result set
```

What might be causing this?

Thank you.

Comment: It might be stupid, but did you check without `" "` or with `"*jon*"`?

Comment: Yes mate sorry it didn't work :( btw does rebuilding the catalog repopulates the index? I just started the process. Thanks.

Comment: It's more likely the full-text index hasn't finished populating.  How big is the table?  Check on the status of the rebuild using DMV sys.fulltext_indexes

Comment: @Stackoverflowuser see http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8644/38055

Comment: Guys the word 'jon' might be a stopword in our database, a word which is useful in some other language. Working on how to check the stoplists and remove a keyword out of it. Thanks.

Comment: How can I remove some English token words (such as "a" or "as" etc) from the stoplist? Thank you.

Comment: You can change your full-text index to use a custom (rather than the system) stop list, then alter it using ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280871.aspx)  However I would question the need to do this.  If someone does actually search for documents containing "a" that will then be most of your documents, somewhat defeating the purpose of full-text indexing.

Comment: Thanks wBob I dont't want to use another stoplist. System is just fine, if only I could remove one particular word off it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the following article:

[Configure and Manage Stopwords and Stoplists for Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-stopwords-and-stoplists-for-full-text-search) (Microsoft Docs)

> To prevent a full-text index from becoming bloated, SQL Server has a mechanism that discards commonly occurring strings that do not help the search. These discarded strings are called stopwords. During index creation, the Full-Text Engine omits stopwords from the full-text index. This means that full-text queries will not search on stopwords.

It contains a general overview of how stoplists work and references a further article that goes on to explain how you can modify stoplists to achieve what you are looking for:

[ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-fulltext-stoplist-transact-sql) (Microsoft Docs)

> Inserts or deletes a stop word in the default full-text stoplist of the current database.

The syntax of the command is as follows:

> ```
> ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST stoplist_name  
> {   
>         ADD [N] 'stopword' LANGUAGE language_term    
>   | DROP   
>     {  
>         'stopword' LANGUAGE language_term   
>       | ALL LANGUAGE language_term   
>       | ALL  
>      }  
> ;
> ```